# How to show only one accordion at time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have several accordion drop downs, which I am able to open each and close each individually, but what i actually want to achieve is

1. to automatically close the other when I open one
2. to close one child when I open another child(for the multilevel accordion)

Here's what I've been able to achieve

```
<div class="a0f13_2aGAs">
    <div class="_5cb4a_2yTAQ"><span>Categories</span></div>
    <ul class="_44ec6_3AFlz" id="accordion">
        <li class="_99e51_2Fldz">
            <button class="accordion"><a href="#y">Main drop 1</a></button>
            <div class="panel">
                <ul class="cat">
                    <li class="cat">
                        <div>
                            <a class="cat" href="#x">
                                <span class="_33353_3KdIO">
                                    PC</span><span class="_3b1e8_3gyVo">
                                    <svg height="16" viewBox="0 0 9 16" width="9"
                                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class=""
                                        name="chevron-next-outline">
                                        <path
                                            d="M.659.65a.532.532 0 0 0 0 .75l6.583 6.593-6.583 6.606a.532.532 0 0 0 0 .75.527.527 0 0 0 .747 0L8.349 8.38a.519.519 0 0 0 .155-.375.54.54 0 0 0-.155-.375L1.406.662A.516.516 0 0 0 .659.65z"
                                            fill="#50545B" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="cat">
                        <div>
                            <a class="cat" href="#x">
                                <span class="_33353_3KdIO">
                                    PC 2</span><span class="_3b1e8_3gyVo">
                                    <svg height="16" viewBox="0 0 9 16" width="9"
                                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class=""
                                        name="chevron-next-outline">
                                        <path
                                            d="M.659.65a.532.532 0 0 0 0 .75l6.583 6.593-6.583 6.606a.532.532 0 0 0 0 .75.527.527 0 0 0 .747 0L8.349 8.38a.519.519 0 0 0 .155-.375.54.54 0 0 0-.155-.375L1.406.662A.516.516 0 0 0 .659.65z"
                                            fill="#50545B" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="_99e51_2Fldz">
            <button class="accordion"><a href="#y">Main drop 2</a></button>
            <div class="panel">
                <ul class="cat">
                    <li class="cat">
                        <button class="accordion ac2" data-parent="#myGroup"><a href="#y">sub drop 1</a></button>
                        <div class="panel">
                            <ul class="cat">
                                <li class="cat">
                                    <div>
                                        <a class="cat" href="#x">
                                            <span class="_33353_3KdIO">
                                                PC</span><span class="_3b1e8_3gyVo">
                                                <svg height="16" viewBox="0 0 9 16" width="9"
                                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class=""
                                                    name="chevron-next-outline">
                                                    <path
                                                        d="M.659.65a.532.532 0 0 0 0 .75l6.583 6.593-6.583 6.606a.532.532 0 0 0 0 .75.527.527 0 0 0 .747 0L8.349 8.38a.519.519 0 0 0 .155-.375.54.54 0 0 0-.155-.375L1.406.662A.516.516 0 0 0 .659.65z"
                                                        fill="#50545B" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                                </svg>
                                            </span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="cat">
                        <button class="accordion ac2" data-parent="#myGroup"><a href="#y">sup drop 2</a></button>
                        <div class="panel">
                            <ul class="cat">
                                <li class="cat">
                                    <div>
                                        <a class="cat" href="#x">
                                            <span class="_33353_3KdIO">
                                                PC</span><span class="_3b1e8_3gyVo">
                                                <svg height="16" viewBox="0 0 9 16" width="9"
                                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class=""
                                                    name="chevron-next-outline">
                                                    <path
                                                        d="M.659.65a.532.532 0 0 0 0 .75l6.583 6.593-6.583 6.606a.532.532 0 0 0 0 .75.527.527 0 0 0 .747 0L8.349 8.38a.519.519 0 0 0 .155-.375.54.54 0 0 0-.155-.375L1.406.662A.516.516 0 0 0 .659.65z"
                                                        fill="#50545B" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                                </svg>
                                            </span>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Please kindly render any assistance to me,

Also please note i tried the  `data-parent="#accordion"` method as shown in some examples, but that didn't work

here a working jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/k7f38es6/

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your original fiddle to accomplish what I think you were trying to achieve.

[modified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y9o6u1mc/6/)

Here's the crux of the code:

```
function openAccordionWindow(){
   for( var closeIndex = 0; closeIndex < acc.length; closeIndex++){
        acc[closeIndex].classList.remove('active');
        var panel = acc[closeIndex].nextElementSibling;
        console.log(panel);
        panel.style.display = 'none';
   }
   this.classList.add("active");
   var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
   panel.style.display = 'block';
   expandParents(panel);
}

function expandParents(target){
   var parent = target.parentElement;
   if(parent.id==='accordion'){
     return;
   }
   if(parent.classList.contains('panel')){
     parent.style.display = 'block';
   }
   parent.classList.add('tagged');
   expandParents(parent);
}
```

Here's generally how I approach it:

- go through all of your accordion elements, and make them closed
- add properties to the one you want to open to open it.
- proceed to the parent element.  If it is a panel, open it too.
- keep recursively calling the expandParents function until you've reached the root of the accordion.  In this case by hitting an element with an id of "accordion".

  - when you reach a panel, expand it.

There are some efficiency problems, but it will accomplish what you want and not be too much of a problem since you'll never really have that many accordions.

Some notes, however, to make it easier in the future.

- try not to use toggle when you want to close/open something.  A lot of people make this mistake, and usually it works out fine, but if the panel was somehow already not "active", you would them make it "active".
- it is a common thing to add anonymous click handlers to event listeners.  This can be problematic both for memory (because each element would have a separate copy of the function)(this is minor) but also just trying to figure out what your code does.  A well-named function can make it immediately obvious what you are trying to do.
- you are adding the class 'active' to elements to make them highlight, and that same class could have also expanded the accordion had your panel been nested inside the accordion itself.  That's not always possible, of course.  The 'active' class could then have modified the display state of nested children.
- it is often better to add a class to do the expansion than to modify the inline style directly.  A class like "activePanel" could have changed the display and given flexibility and made it easier to add additional properties.
- You might not always have your panels immediately following your switching element.  In an accordion this is probably going to be the case, but in pill menus and such or tab panels, they might be removed by some distance or not in the direct parent / child flow.  You might look into attaching custom attributes to the accordion tab and the panel to allow the selection of other elements that are not immediate siblings.  The [bootstrap collapse](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp) module does something similar to this.
- assuming you are not constrained by some requirement of language or libraries/frameworks, there are a number of things that could have made this a much simpler task for you.  jquery selectors and methods, as well as things like materialize and bootstrap offer this sort of functionality, just to name a few.

Edit 
 - added additional code to expand child submenus as well, as well as an expanded explanation of how that works.

Comment: thank you, it works, but i noticed the sub drops are no longer expandable

Comment: They weren't expandable in the original jsfiddle, either, no?  I thought they were just entries that happened to have > after them.

If you want to have subfolders, you would need to incorporate a structure that was reproducible.  I'll try to make a simpler example that would be less headache prone as the method you started with.

Comment: If you're looking for pretty comprehensive functionality without a lot of work on your part, you might want to look into bootstrap collapsables. 

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp

Comment: Yeah they actually were expandable in the original fiddle, also that was the exact tutorials i used to get to where I am now, but could get the auto close to work for me

Comment: This jsbin expands sub elements.  Though it does have the problem of clicking on sub items that don't expand will also close the parent:
https://jsbin.com/nihuwa/edit?js,output

Comment: @Drwho   Here is a version of the modified fiddle with the ability to expand sub elements.  It does the same "expand parents" procedure I did on the jsbin I linked above, but tailored to your structure. https://jsfiddle.net/y9o6u1mc/6/

Comment: thanks, it works, i've accepted your answer, but is there a way to open the sub element while keeping the red color of the main element and the gray color of the sub together, also it possible to close the element when you click on it again?

Comment: You could see if the current display is block of the element you are on, and if it is, don't open it, just let the close happen.  As for the colors, I believe your active class handles that?  If you added a class to the current one of 'active', then to any successive elements that get opened in the "expandParent" function, you could add a different class that gives the gray color.  Assuming you want the direct clicked element to be red, and the parent elements to be grey.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196063/discussion-between-dr-who-and-daniel-paschal).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. I haven't fully tested this out but this should work.
Hope this helps.

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        resetAccordian(this);
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
            this.classList.remove("active");
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}


resetAccordian = (originalTarget) => {
    let accordians = Object.values(acc);
    accordians.forEach( data => {
        if (data != originalTarget) {
            let target = data.nextElementSibling;
            data.classList.remove("active");
            if (target.style.display === "block") {
                target.style.display = "none";
            }
        } else {
            data.classList.add("active");
        }  
    }, originalTarget);
}
```

Comment: thanks, this works as well, but I noticed the sub drops are no longer expandable